# Combining a ggplot and plotRGB in one PNG plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, raster

I am trying to combine a ggplot result and a plotRGB of a spatial raster into one plot and write it to PNG. I have already found how to combine ggplots or do a multiplot but this specific setup I do not know how to get to work. This code is also integrated in a for-loop, which means that a print statement needs to be used to actually plot the ggplot (in either PNG or Rstudio).

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

plotRGB(brick(raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)),
              raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)),
              raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100))),r=1,g=2,b=3,stretch="lin")
ggdata=data.frame("x"=seq(100),"y"=rnorm(100))
ggplot(ggdata,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()
```

Does anyone of you know how to combine these two into a PNG (favorably shown in a for-loop, but not necessary)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `plotRGB` is using `base` graphics and `ggplot2` is using `grid` graphics, to combine them we can use `gridBase` package. This code seems to work

```
require("raster")
require("ggplot2")
require("gridBase")
require("grid")
require("gridExtra")

png("gg.png", width = 600, height = 1200)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=1, height=0.5, y = .75))
par(omi=gridOMI())
par(mfrow=c(2, 2), mfg=c(1, 1), mar=c(3, 3, 1, 0))
for (i in 1:3) {
  plotRGB(brick(raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)),
                raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)),
                raster(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100))),r=1,g=2,b=3,stretch="lin")
}
upViewport()

pushViewport(viewport(width=1, height=0.5, y = .25))
ggdata=data.frame("x"=seq(100),"y"=rnorm(100))
grid.draw(ggplotGrob(
  ggplot(ggdata,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_line() ))
upViewport()
dev.off()
```

This produces following png:
[image]

I advise you to get familiar with the documentation of used packages to be able to draw what you need in the way you want :)

Comment: Thank you! I adapted your code to my own objects and it worked.